# Add condition to map function

Tags: javascript

I have this `map` function:

```
  return docTypes.map(docType => ({
    label: docType.docType,
    value: docType.id,
  }));
```

How can I add a condition to return only if `docType.generic = true`?

Comment: use filter instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before your `map`:

```js
return docTypes.filter(docType => docType.generic).map(docType => ({
  label: docType.docType,
  value: docType.id,
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can combine .filter and .map

```
return docTypes.filter(docType => docType.generic)
  .map(docType => ({
    label: docType.docType,
    value: docType.id,
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, to just iterate once on the array you can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const docTypes = [
    {docType: "csv", id: 10, generic: true},
    {docType: "txt", id: 20, generic: false},
    {docType: "wav", id: 30, generic: true}
];

let res = docTypes.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    if (curr.generic)
        res.push({label: curr.docType, value: curr.id});

    return res;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```